# Can I use __autoload in class?

Tags: php

Can I use `__autoload` function on class that after to include file (class)?

I tried this only outside of class. So, I loop array with names of classes and try to include them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whilst the __autoload() function can also be used for autoloading classes and interfaces, its preferred to use the spl_autoload_register() function. This is because it is a more flexible alternative (enabling for any number of autoloaders to be specified in the application, such as in third party libraries). For this reason, using __autoload() is discouraged and it may **be deprecated in the future**.
>
> Autoloading is **not available** if using PHP in CLI interactive mode.

Saying above you can still do it as shown below:

```
<?php
    spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
        include $class_name . '.php';
    });

    // example 

    $pet = new Dog();  // this class will be auto loaded from file Dog.php.
```

Comment: So, but if this class has file name is: dog.php or Dog.php?

Comment: from Dog.php, as a best Practise try to keep file name same as class name.

Comment: Yes, I know, but if will any case when I dont know file name? Only assume that it has D or d. Does autoload include therefore then?

Comment: @Huligan you need to define the code that the autoloader uses.  You can make it do just about anything.  In this example, `$class_name` will be passed to the autoloader as the name of the class you call, for example if you instantiate `Dog` and the class `Dog` is not defined, it will call the autoloader with the argument `Dog`.